# How to select specific number of rows depending on condition from a table using SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

I am storing photo images in a SQL Server database. The images are stored using a column called `PhotoType`.

PhotoTypes are many - some of them are:

```
CheckList, Installation, Audit, SignOff ...
```

Now I want 2 photos for CheckList, 2 photos for Installation, 1 photo for Audit and 1 Photo for SignOff, to be selected from the database (for each customer).

So there will be totally 6 photos to be selected, though the database may have many photos for the customer.

How can I do this in a SQL query?

Thanks and regards

Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by Customer, PhotoType
      order by Id)
  from Photo 
  where PhotoType in ('CheckList','Installation','Audit','SignOff')
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1 
  or (rn = 2 and PhotoType in ('CheckList','Installation');
```

Using a subquery (derived table) instead of the `cte`:

```
select *
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by Customer, PhotoType
      order by Id)
  from Photo 
  where PhotoType in ('CheckList','Installation','Audit','SignOff')
  ) as sub
where rn = 1 
  or (rn = 2 and PhotoType in ('CheckList','Installation');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select top 2 * from temp# where [Type]='CheckList'
   union all
   select top 2 * from temp# where [Type]='Installation'
   union all
   select top 1 * from temp# where [Type]='Audit'
   union all
   select top 1 * from temp# where [Type]='SignOff'
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.